# Raytracing the 'sunshape'

Tags: graphics, raytracing, sampling, montecarlo

This is based on the question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17083173/sampling-a-hemisphere-using-an-arbitary-distribtuion), but I think I might have asked the question in the wrong way. This is my problem: 
I am writing a *scientific* ray tracer. I.e. not for graphics although the concepts are identical.

I am firing rays from a horizontal plane toward a parabolic  dish with a focus distance of 100m (and perfect specular reflection).  I have a Target at the focal point of the dish. The rays are not fired perpendicularly from the plane but are perturbed by a certain angle to emulate the fact that the sun is not a point source but a disc in the sky.

However, the flux coming form the sun is not radially constant across the sun disc. Its hotter in the middle than at the edges. If you have ever looked at the sun on a hazy day you'll see a ring around the sun.

Because of the parabolic dish, the reflected image on the Target should be the image of the sun.  i.e. It should be brighter (hotter, more flux) in the middle than at the edges. This is given by a graph with Intensity Vs. Radial distance from the center

There is two ways I can simulate this.

**Firstly: Uniform Sampling**: Each rays is shot out from the with a equal (uniform)  probability of taking an angle between zero and the size of the sun disk. I then scale the flux carried by the ray according to the corresponding flux value at that angle.

**Secondly: Arbitrarily Sampling**: Each rays is shot out from the plane according to the distribution of the Intensity Vs. Radial Distance. Therefore there will be *less* rays toward the outer edges than rays within the centre. This, to me seems far more efficient. But I can not get it to work. Any suggenstions?

This is what I have done:

**Uniformly**

```
phi = 2*pi*X_1
alpha = arccos (1-(1-cos(theta))*X_2)
x = sin(alpha)*cos(phi)
y = sin(alpha)*sin*phi
z = -cos(alpha)
```

Where `X` is a uniform random number and `theta` is a the subtend angle of the Solar Disk.

**Arbitarily Sampling**

```
alpha = arccos (1-(1-cos(theta)) B1)
```

Where `B` is a random number generated from an arbiatry distribution using the algorithm on pg 27 [here](http://graphics.ucsd.edu/courses/cse168_s06/ucsd/lecture09.pdf).

I am desperate to sort this out.

Comment: This never gets around to actually asking a question.

Comment: I believe what you are trying to do is called "importance sampling" and yes it should be more efficient if you can get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

your function drops to zero and since the sun is not a smooth surfaced object, that is probably wrong. Chances are there are photons emitting at all parts of the sun in all directions.

But: what is your actual QUESTION?

Comment: How do I sample a hemisphere with and an arbitrarily distribution. But I guess my route question is: "How do I generate rays, giving them a direction based on an arbitrary distribution" (Does that make sense? Im sorry if my explanation is hard to follow. Trying my best to make it understandable. Would a picture help?)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [Monte-Carlo integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_integration).
The key idea is: although you will sample less rays outside of the disc, you will weight these rays more and they will contribute to the sum with a higher importance.

While with a uniform sampling, you just sum your intensity values, with a non uniform sampling, you divide each intensity by the value of the probability distribution of the rays that are shot (e.g., for a uniform distribution, this value is a constant and doesn't change anything).